# Laravel foreach : Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, view, crud

I want to display my categories on my website in the template layout.. I get the error : "Undefined variable: categories".

I can't find how to get this foreach works.

Template code :

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<a class="nav-item nav-link text-white" href="#"><span>{{ $category->name }}</span></a>
@endforeach
```

HomeController :

```
    public function public(){
        $home = DB::table('products')->get();
        $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();

        return view('home.index')->with([
            'products' => $home,
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
```

home.index view :

```
@extends('layouts.template')
@section('title', 'Accueil')
@section('content')
@component('components.home', ['homes' => $home, 'categories' => $categories, 'mode' => 'public'])
@endcomponent
@endsection
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/shop','HomeController@public')->name('shop.index');
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two notes: first, are you sure that your function is called public. Second in your view you pass variable $home to the component, where does that variable come from because it is not passed from the controller to the view.

Comment: Yes I called the function public. I have others functions like store, edit and update where i'm using the $home. That's why i pass the variable $home in the component.

Comment: I was wondering maybe if i add "@extends('layouts.template', ['categories' => $category, 'mode' => 'public'])" in the view, it'will work but no, same error. it doesn't know the variable  "categories".

Comment: I updated my post with the HomeController. Now the $home is called in my view. Still the same though :(

Comment: You must update the component to receive the categories array variable : @component('components.home', ['homes' => $home, 'categories' => $categories, 'mode' => 'public'] )

Comment: I did like you said, but still the same error "undefined variable categories" . it shows me the template with the line @foreach ($categories as $category).